# Fetch only unique data from the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have data in an array. The data looks like this

```
Array
(
    [1-2] => Array
        (
            [-LTTzVgH1H4-mCg9vUPT] => Array
                (
                    [chat_id] => -LTTzVgH1H4-mCg9vUPT

                    [receiver_id] => 10215158688973543
                    [sender_id] => 1934076580016543

                )

        )
)
```

So Basically It has been structured like this

```
1-2
3-4
5-6
2-1
6-5
```

I want to fetch only those keys which are unique. Meaning I want to get the result like this

```
1-2
3-4
5-6
```

How can I fetch only unique keys data?

**Note:** Both `1-2` or `2-1` has the same data

This is what I've tried

```
foreach($json_data as $key=>$value){
   echo $key.'<br>';


}
```

This gives me all the keys atm

Comment: What you've tried to so far ?

Comment: @Sanu0786 I have updated my question

Comment: Why are the keys of your array structured like that? What does this data represent?

Comment: how key 1-2 is same as 2-1??

Comment: Well I am using firebase for chat. 1 - 2 meaning that the user id 1 has sent a message to user id 2.. and when user id 2 sends a message to 1 it creates another node. so basically both have the same data. so I just need one

Comment: Is the data inside 2-1 the same as 1-2? can you include an example of your data for that "duplicate" key?

Comment: @Scuzzy yes both have the same data

Comment: I'd focus on trying to prevent duplication returning from the database rather than trying to filter it out once it's been retrieved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could "reorder" the keys, then remove duplicate ones:

```
$unique_keys = array_unique(array_map(function ($key) {
  $parts = explode('-', $key);
  sort($parts);
  return implode('-', $parts);
}, array_keys($array)));
```

**Demo here: https://3v4l.org/Fr1qD**

Comment: @jeto Thank you very much. It worked. This is what I was looking for